# How to work with Magento staging env?

Tags: ee-1.12, staging

I need to prepare content and when the time is coming schedule merge on the main website. I think that I can use staging env for this purpose. But it's seems not working or I'm doing something wrong.

I'm creating new cms page on staging, I change setting at BO for staging to show this page as home page. After it I go to staging and plan merge. After merge I expect that created cms page will be home page. But nothing happens. What I'm doing wrong? How to make created cms page on staging home page on live?

Comment: Silly question but did you publish the changes?

Comment: Actually I refused to use this. During those stagings there were a lot of table copies and db become enormous.

Comment: so did you solve this issue another way?

Comment: Yes. It was necessary to populate CMS pages in this way. But we created a field publish_date for cms pages and created them on live.

Comment: feel free to post your solution as answer as it may help others.

Comment: this solution is specific one, just other view on this problem and not related to staging.

Answer (score 1):

this is an enterprise feature.

Maybe this helps: https://github.com/magento-hackathon/firegento-contentsync

It is a module to sync a lot of stuff, e.g. cms pages and blocks